# memcache loadbalance/failover plan

Tags: memcached, load-balancing

I wanna know if there is any loadbalance/failover plan for memcache. 
I'm using JAVA client. I knew some client implementions can talk with multi memcache servers, but how about loadbalance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should double check your client libraries.  PHP and some other libraries provide consistant hashing.  This way if one server fails, the keys are redirected to another.

Answer (score 1):

Memcached itself [does not](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#How_does_memcached_handle_failover?) although it does use a hashing algorithm to distribute keys across a cluster.  However, some clients do provide failover mechanisms but that depends on your language AND client.

For instance, in the perl cpan libraries Cache::Memcached does provide failover in a cluster if one server goes down while Cache::Memcached::Fast does not.